# Bootstrap columns shrink instead of stacking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my landing page, we have a "Media Resource" section with links to videos, support materials and social media. Currently, the content in the section shrinks when the window is resized rather than the wanted outcome of stacking.

To be clear, the Videos, Support, and Social are what should be stacking. The heading of the section is perfectly fine.

[image: Columns shrinking]

I've looked through the HTML and CSS for the section but can't seem to pinpoint what's causing them not to stack like desired. Below is the HTML and CSS for what's being worked on.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid no-gutters media-resource-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 text-center">
            <h2 class="boxheader-lead">Media & Public Relations Resource Center</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-lg-2">
            <img src="~/Images/Video.png" alt="videos" class="img-fluid media-icon video" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <img src="~/Images/Materials.png" alt="support materials" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 col-lg-2">
            <img src="~/Images/Social.png" alt="social" class="img-fluid media-icon social" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.media-resource-wrapper {
    background-color: #00b9f2;
    padding: 60px 0;
}

    .media-resource-wrapper > .row {
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

    .media-resource-wrapper h2 {
          margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;

n-bottom: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Media resourse icon positioning */
.media-resource-wrapper .media-icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {

.health-professionals-block .boxheader-landing {
    left: 30px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    width: 20%;
}

.boxheader-landing h1, .boxheader-landing h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

.boxheader-landing-copy {
    font-size: .9em;
}

.media-resource-wrapper h2 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.media-resource-wrapper .media-icon {
    top: 30px;
}

.media-resource-wrapper {
    padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
}
```

}

**UPDATE**
I made a change that was recommended but the images below shows how it looks by default and then when I shrink.

Standard Size:
[image]

Smaller window:
[image]

Comment: Not sure how to clarify it more. The videos, materials and social columns shrink when resizing to smaller windows rather than stack. I want them to stack. The image is exactly what's happening when the window resizes. It just gets smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use standard bootstrap class `col-sm-3` and `col-sm-6`.

Replace the URL with your image and it will stack.

```css
.media-resource-wrapper {
  background-color: #00b9f2;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

.media-resource-wrapper>.row {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.media-resource-wrapper h2 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  n-bottom: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Media resourse icon positioning */

.media-resource-wrapper .media-icon {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .health-professionals-block .boxheader-landing {
    left: 30px;
    margin-top: 250px;
    width: 20%;
  }
  .boxheader-landing h1,
  .boxheader-landing h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
  }
  .boxheader-landing-copy {
    font-size: .9em;
  }
  .media-resource-wrapper h2 {
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    padding-right: 30px;
  }
  .media-resource-wrapper .media-icon {
    top: 30px;
  }
  .media-resource-wrapper {
    padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid no-gutters media-resource-wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 text-center">
      <h2 class="boxheader-lead">Media & Public Relations Resource Center</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gN6iBKP1b2GTXZZoCxhyXiYIAh8QJ_8xzlhEK6csyDadA4GdkEdIEy9Bc8s5jozt1g=w300" alt="videos" class="img-fluid media-icon video" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gN6iBKP1b2GTXZZoCxhyXiYIAh8QJ_8xzlhEK6csyDadA4GdkEdIEy9Bc8s5jozt1g=w300" alt="support materials" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gN6iBKP1b2GTXZZoCxhyXiYIAh8QJ_8xzlhEK6csyDadA4GdkEdIEy9Bc8s5jozt1g=w300" alt="social" class="img-fluid media-icon social" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="container-fluid no-gutters media-resource-wrapper">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-12  text-center">
    <h2 class="boxheader-lead">Media & Public Relations Resource 
 Center</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3 ">
    <img src="~/Images/Video.png" alt="videos" class="img-fluid media-
 icon video" />
</div>
<div class="col-6 ">
    <img src="~/Images/Materials.png" alt="support materials" 
class="img-fluid" />
</div>
<div class="col-3 ">
    <img src="~/Images/Social.png" alt="social" class="img-fluid 
 media-icon social" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the columns to stack use `col-sm-` instead...

https://www.codeply.com/go/kQHOYSTEnL

```
<div class="container-fluid no-gutters media-resource-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 text-center">
            <h2 class="boxheader-lead">Media & Public Relations Resource Center</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200" alt="videos" class="img-fluid media-icon video" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 text-center">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200" alt="support materials" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
            <img src="//placehold.it/200" alt="social" class="img-fluid media-icon social" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see here, the `.col-` is the smallest breakpoint, so they will continue to shrink horizontally in width. `sm` is the next size up so they will become full-width, and stack vertically at 576px. If you want the cols to stack at wider widths use `col-md-`,`col-lg-` or `col-xl-`, etc..

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container-fluid no-gutters media-resource-wrapper">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12  text-center">
        <h2 class="boxheader-lead">Media & Public Relations Resource Center</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 ">
        <img src="~/Images/Video.png" alt="videos" class="img-fluid media-icon video" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 ">
        <img src="~/Images/Materials.png" alt="support materials" class="img-fluid" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 ">
        <img src="~/Images/Social.png" alt="social" class="img-fluid media-icon social" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: making those changes doesn't help. It ultimately breaks the columns. I've updated the main article